# no appropriate default constructor available . (when creating a child class)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am creating some custom exception classes doing the following

```
class GXException
{
public:
    GXException(LPCWSTR pTxt):pReason(pTxt){};
    LPCWSTR pReason;
};

class GXVideoException : GXException
{
public:
    GXVideoException(LPCWSTR pTxt):pReason(pTxt){};
    LPCWSTR pReason;
};
```

When I created GXVideoException to extend GXException, I get the following error

```
1>c:\users\numerical25\desktop\intro todirectx\godfiles\gxrendermanager\gxrendermanager\gxrendermanager\gxexceptions.h(14) : error C2512: 'GXException' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using private inheritance?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your base class constructor inside your derived constructor's initializer list.  Also since you are deriving from the base class you should not redeclare a second variable by the same name (`pReason`).

```
class GXException
{
public:
    GXException(LPCWSTR pTxt):pReason(pTxt){};
    LPCWSTR pReason;
};

class GXVideoException : GXException
{
public:
    GXVideoException(LPCWSTR pTxt)
    : GXException(pTxt)
    {}
};
```

Comment: O ok, I never knew this. So anytime my base class accepts arguments in it's constructor, I need to call it from the parent class ??

Comment: @numerical25: Yes if you don't specify one it will try to call a base constructor with no parameters.  In your case you don't have one hence your error.

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer is correct, but I also find it helpful to define an 'inherited' type so that I don't have too many references to the parent class to maintain, in case the hierarchy changes.

```
class GXVideoException : GXException
{
private:
    typedef GXEception inherited;
public:
    GXVideoException(LPCWSTR pTxt)
    : inherited(pTxt)
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a default constructor:

```
class GXException
{
public:
    GXException() : pReason("") {};
    GXException(LPCWSTR pTxt):pReason(pTxt){};
    LPCWSTR pReason;
};
```

Or as Brian says, call the base constructor from your derived exception.