# MessageBox does not work in a catch of an exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Well I have 2 issues but my main concern right now is my catch exception. Here is the code...

```
int GXRenderManager::Ignite(HINSTANCE * hinst, int * nCmd, GXDEVICE DeviceType, int width, int height)
{
 try
 {
  GXRenderManager::hinstance = hinst;
  GXRenderManager::nCmdShow = nCmd;

  GXRenderManager::height = height;
  GXRenderManager::width = width;

  InitWindows();

  switch(DeviceType)
  {
  case DIRECTX:
   GXRenderManager::renderDevice = new GXDX;
   break;
  case OPENGL:
   GXRenderManager::renderDevice = new GXGL;
   break;
  default:
   throw GXException(L"Error Finding Video Device"); 
  }

  Device()->StartUp(GXRenderManager::mainWindow ,width, height); //Error happens here
 }
 catch(GXVideoException &e)
 {
  MessageBox(0,e.pReason,L"GXVideoException",1);//Catch happens but no message box
  return 0;
 }
 catch(GXWindowsException &e)
 {
  MessageBox(0,e.pReason,L"Windows Error",1);
  return 0;
 }
 catch(GXException &e)
 {
  MessageBox(0,e.pReason,L"Error",1);
  return 0;
 }

 return 1;
}
```

Here is where the error happens

```
void GXDX::StartUp(HWND* mainWindow,int w, int h)
{
 width = w;
 height = h;
 this->mainWindow = mainWindow;

 ID3D10Texture2D *backBufferSurface;

 DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
 swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
 swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
 swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
 swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
 swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
 swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
 swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
 swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
 swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *mainWindow;
 swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;

 D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;

 HRESULT hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,driverType,NULL,0,
  D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc,&swapChain,&dxDevice);

 if(FAILED(hr))
  throw GXVideoException(L"Problems retrieving directX device");
}
```

When I do a walk through. the D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain returns a failure, therefore triggering the GXVideoException error.

It then catches and returns back to GXRenderManager class as shown below.

```
catch(GXVideoException &e)
 {
  MessageBox(0,e.pReason,L"GXVideoException",1);
  return 0;
 }
```

At this point in time, If I put my cursor over the &e, I clearly see my message "Problems retrieving directX device". But the message box does not show

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
 if(GXRenderManager::Ignite(&hInstance, &nCmdShow,DIRECTX) != 1)
  return 0;
      //NEVER REACHES THE RUN METHOD BELOW YET THE MAIN WINDOW REMAINS OPEN
 GXRenderManager::Run();

 return 0;
}
```

Another thing I find strange is that my created window remains showing but never reaches the main loop. It is like the application is idle due to the message box, but the message box is not showing...

I also would like to add that the static member renderDevice is a interface datatype. GXDX is of course a implemented class of the interface.

GXDX class includes the GXException Header so it is able to throw those exceptions so the main GXRenderManager can catch them.

[EDIT]

Another thing I would like to add is if I remove the Show window method

```
ShowWindow(*GXRenderManager::mainWindow, *GXRenderManager::nCmdShow);
```

It works. So as long as my main application window is not open. My message box appears like its suppose to.

[EDIT]

Prior to dauphic response which fixed part of the problem, I went on and edited my code. My catch now looks like this

```
catch(GXVideoException &e)
    {
        MessageBox(*GXRenderManager::mainWindow,e.pReason,L"GXVideoException",1);
        return 0;
    }
```

But now my application opens and then immediately closes without displaying the box. mainWindow is a pointer to my base window. So I had to dereference the pointer.

[EDIT]

The windows pointer is bad

Comment: What is the type of `e.pReason`?
I'd take a guess that it is a std::wstring and not a wchar_t

Comment: [An earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070366/no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-when-creating-a-child-class) indicates that it's an `LPCWSTR`. Besides, @Greg, if a type mismatch were the problem, the code wouldn't even have compiled.

Comment: Quite right, having a 'moment'.
I was thinking more along the lines of a 'bad pointer', a la printf not converting string, but using the std::string.

Comment: Who calls an API function with parameters like 0 and 1 without an explaining comment nearby?

Comment: Windows programmers. What 0 and 1 stand for are obvious to anyone familiar with winapi. If a person doesn't understand what 0 and 1 are, they probably have no business dealing with winapi code.

Comment: @Greg, well you did help me some what. The problem was as Dauphic stated. I did not pass the pointer to the parent window. At the same time I another issue arised,  and the windows pointer just so happens to be bad. Which now that I think about it is strange. because why would the parent window open but no pointer is returned.

Comment: @dauphic, If you don't want to help then dont make a comment. I am not asking for my skills to be scrutinize. I am learning.

Comment: I have same problem, MessageBox not shown in catch block, could be the reason that there's no message loop running? I'm catching std::exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a dialog is present, MessageBox should always be passed a handle to it, rather than 0. Only pass MessageBox 0 if no dialog is available.

Side note, I don't understand the exact reason for this, so it would be great if someone else could give insight.

It's also possible that your message box is being attached to your dialog, and because your dialog isn't active, the message box isn't showing. Pressing alt when it hangs may cause it to show.

Comment: I was afraid that was part of the issue. I am not a pro with WINAPI or C++ so I was not sure precisely what arguments went into messageBox. I tried to research the parameters but did not have the time cause I had to go to work. I went on and passed HWND into the first arguement instead of 0 and now the application runs and shuts down without displaying the box. I edited the code above